# Supporting multiple abstract class versions without explicitly specifying the version

Tags: c++, abstract-class

I'm building a dll where I am trying to support multiple versions of an abstract class.

```
enum VersionInfo
{
    Base, 
    Derived1, 
    Dervied2
}

class IBase
{
public:
    virtual int GetProperty1() const = 0; 
    virtual int GetProperty2() const = 0;

    virtual VersionInfo GetVersion() const 
    {
        return VersionInfo::Base;
    }
}

class IDerived1 : public IBase
{
public:
    virtual int GetProperty1() const override = 0;

    virtual int GetProperty2() const override final
    {
        return 0; 
    }

    virtual VersionInfo GetVersion() const override final
    {
        return VersionInfo::Derived1;
    }
}

class IDerived2 : public IBase
{
public:
    virtual int GetProperty1() const override final
    {
        return 0; 
    }

    virtual int GetProperty2() const override = 0;

    virtual VersionInfo GetVersion() const override final
    {
        return VersionInfo::Derived2;
    }
}
```

The GetVersion() tells an API on what property to look at. So in a different file, I have

```
int TakeAction(const IBase &object)
{
    switch (object.GetVersion())
    {
        case VersionInfo::Derived1:
            int property = object.GetProperty1();
            // Take some action
            break;

        case VersionInfo::Derived2:
            int property = object.GetProperty2();
            // Take some action
            break; 

        case VersionInfo::Base:
        default:
            // report error
            break;
    }
}
```

The reason why I am doing this is so that later on if I want to support a 3rd, and 4th version with new properties (and I know that there will be a 3rd and 4th and more), I should be able to add "final" implementations of the new properties in existing IDerived classes, so that when I publish a new dll, the existing consumers of my dll won't break.

However, my question is, is it possible to do this without explicitly storing the version of the interface in it. That way the implementation is truly polymorphic.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Jarod42.

Comment: I have changed the question details now.

Comment: Why have a `GetVersion`  whereas a unique `virtual std::string GetProperty() = 0;` seems enough.

Comment: That is essentially doing the same thing as I am, right? 

However, I figured what I need here is a dynamic_cast

So in the API I can do something like, 



IDerived1 *derived1 = std::dynamic_cast<IDerived1*>(basePtr);
IDerived2 *derived2 = std::dynamic_cast<IDerived1*>(basePtr);

And only one conversion will give me a non-nullptr

Comment: I think it is similar and simpler. `dynamic_cast` is still possible.

Comment: I solved this by passing in a shared_ptr of the base type to the function, and then doing a dynamic_pointer_cast inside it. This eliminated the needs for the version.